# Is there a way to see the salt state converted to the actual command that is being run?

Tags: django, vagrant, salt-stack

I have a state like

```
django.syncdb:
    module.run:
        - settings_module: mvod.dev_settings
        - bin_env: /home/vagrant/virtualenv/
        - migrate: True
        - require:
            - pip: mvod
            - mysql_grants: mvod_user_grants
            - file: /tmp/mvod.log
```

The docs aren't very specific about what this exactly does, though it indeed does seem to do what I expect, meaning run the command `django-admin.py syncdb --settings=mvod.dev_settings --migrate` from inside the directory `/home/vagrant/virtualenv`.

It actually fails to do this, since the `/home/vagrant/virtualenv/` path actually needs to set to `/home/vagrant/virtualenv/bin/django-admin.py`.

However, i ran this in an environment where django wasn't installed, and so i'd expect this to fail. The state however returned `Result: True` but then the output was this `Is a directory`

I figured out eventually that i have to replace the line `bin_env: /home/vagrant/virtualenv/` with `bin_env: /home/vagrant/virtualenv/bin/django-admin.py` since that's what i was trying to call.

Bottom line: i would have figured it out much sooner had i had a way of turning the state into the exact command being executed.

So is there a way to do this real fast?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same problem over here. Neither -l debug nor logfile (/var/log/salt/minion) actually show the command. Version: salt-minion 2015.5.8 (Lithium)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the minion as `salt-minion --log-level=debug` and then execute the state. It will show you what commands are being executed by salt on the system based on your state file.

Comment: i didn't actually use salt-minion, I ran a masterless configuration. I'll see how this fits in however, so thanks!